# Android: how to switch from 1 view to another?

Tags: android

I just started learning Android yesterday and would like to code a very simple app that consists of 2 views for learning purpose.

Activity/View 1: 1 button and a text "Hello World"
On clicking the button, it should go to the next activity/view which only has text "testing".

Here's my code for activity 1:

```
package helloworld.app;


import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.view.Menu; 
import android.view.MenuItem; import
android.support.v4.app.NavUtils; 
/*import AudioRecordTest;*/

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
     return true;
 }

 public void startRecording() {
    setContentView(R.layout.next_page);
 }
  }
```

Here's my code for activity 2:
    package helloworld.app;

```
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.app.Activity; import
android.view.Menu; 
import android.view.MenuItem; import
android.support.v4.app.NavUtils; 
/*import AudioRecordTest;*/

public class next_page extends Activity {

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.next_page);
 } }
```

Here's my code for xml file for activity 1:

```
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
     android:text="@string/hello_world"
     tools:context=".MainActivity" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
     android:text="Start Recording"
     android:onClick="startRecording" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT:
Here are my error messages from logcat

> 08-01 07:00:49.253: I/Choreographer(1326): Skipped 40 frames!  The
>   application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>
> 08-01 07:01:11.653: D/AndroidRuntime(1326): Shutting down VM
>
> 08-01 07:01:11.653: W/dalvikvm(1326): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
>
> 08-01 07:01:11.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1326): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 08-01 07:01:11.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method
>   startRecording(View) in the activity class helloworld.app.MainActivity
>   for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id
>   'button1'
>
> 08-01 07:01:11.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):   at
>   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3578)
>
> 08-01 07:01:11.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):   at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
>
> 08-01 07:01:11.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):   at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
>
> 08-01 07:01:11.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):   at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>
> 08-01 07:01:11.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>
> 08-01 07:01:11.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>
> 08-01 07:01:11.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>
> 08-01 07:01:11.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 08-01 07:01:11.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>
> 08-01 07:01:11.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>
> 08-01 07:01:11.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>
> 08-01 07:01:11.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 08-01 07:01:11.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1326): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: startRecording [class
>   android.view.View]
>
> 08-01 07:01:11.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):   at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
>
> 08-01 07:01:11.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):   at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
>
> 08-01 07:01:11.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):   at
>   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3571)
>
> 08-01 07:01:11.673: E/AndroidRuntime(1326):   ... 11 more

EDIT2:
I found my mistake! I am supposed to pass in View view for my startRecording function. Here's the edited code:

```
public void startRecording(View view) 
{
Intent intent = new Intent(this, next_page.class);  
startActivity(intent); 
}
```

Comment: What's your question, exactly? Is this code not working? Working in an undesired way? Something else?

Comment: It crashed when I clicked on the button.

Comment: Please post the exception stack trace.

Comment: Read this: http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html but if you don't want to.
Classes starts with capital letter, methods with a small letter, you dont use _ in class names but if a 2 word class name as next_page should be NextPage.

Comment: @TedHopp, how do I get the exception stack trace? I would love to see some forms of bug reports when my app crashes but wasn't able to find it anywhere.

Comment: Are you running this in an emulator or a real device? Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: I am running it on the emulator and is using Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it work this should be your `startRecording` method:

```
public void startRecording(View v) {     
    // setContentView(R.layout.next_page); this will modify the current activity view
    // if you want to start a new activity:
    Intent i = new Intent(this, next_page.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Make sure you have declared both activities in the manifest file.
For android to "see" and use your activities the must be declared in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
// ...
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".next_page" />
// ...
```

You should read from the android developers site or some tutorials, this is basic stuff.

Comment: +1 for actually fully reading his xml haha. I just realized he had that onClick attribute set. Too lazy to so I'll go with you :)

Comment: what do you mean by declaring both activities in the manifest file?

Comment: @Sakura See my edited answer. Android must know about each activity your app is going to use and you let it know by declaring the activities in the manifest.

Comment: Do I just add "<activity android:name=".next_page" />" right after the mainactivity? It still crashes my app when I clicked on the button.

Comment: @Sakura You simple add this line `<activity android:name=".next_page" />` to the `AndroidManifest.xml` after the MainActivity part but between the <application></application> tags. If you have errors you should add the stacktrace with the exception from the logcat and see what it tells you.

Comment: How do I add the stacktrace withthe exception from logcat?

Comment: @Sakura See this image http://i.imgur.com/XoY1E.png .After you get those lines with the exception, edit the question and add them.

Answer (score 1):

**You can go to an  Activity from one Activity using Intent class**

```
public void startRecording(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

}

```
Add your Android Manifest configuration file



   <activity android:name="NewActivity"></activity>
```

Comment: Do you mean like adding the code into the startRecording function? Something like this:     public void startRecording() {
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, next_page.class);
     startActivity(intent);
    }

Comment: You are exactly  right. Now I edited my code that you are described.

Answer (score 0):

Use the indent to switch between the activity.
Sample code

btnNextScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //Starting a new Intent
            Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondScreenActivity.class);

            //Sending data to another Activity
            nextScreen.putExtra("name", inputName.getText().toString());
            nextScreen.putExtra("email", inputEmail.getText().toString());

            Log.e("n", inputName.getText()+"."+ inputEmail.getText());

            startActivity(nextScreen);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you assuming what triggers the next Activity is the Button, I would do:

```
Button butt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
butt.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener(
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext());
        //optionally, you could provide it stuff to send to the second Activity if you wish
        startActivity(intent);
    }
));
```

But honestly, you could have figured this out on your own through research.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, onClickListener is related to clicking on any place on the current view. However, I want to click on the button to go to the next view.

Comment: No, whatever you set it to becomes clickable. In this case, the button. In either case, Luksprog's is the easiest. Quick, simple, and I suggest doing that one. But the Intent part will be the same regardless.

Answer (score 0):

startRecording - bad code.
need write:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, next_page.class));
```

And learn how to format code

Answer (score 0):

In onCreate method of first activity write like below

```
Button button1=(Button)findViewById(r.id.button1);

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);  
            }
        });
```